# Adding to an array in VBA with strings as the index

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, vbscript

Not sure I've labelled this correctly.

I have a bunch of cells containing strings of data.  Each cell consists of something like this:

```
q1 = 1   | q2 = 3.2 | q3 = 5.6
q1 = 1.8 | q3 = 2.1 | q5 = 1.4
```

*Note: The delimiter is litteral, all that text is in a single cell, with a pipe char.

I want to loop through each cell, explode (to use the PHP term) by the pipe (|) delimiter, and then do so again by the = sign.

I want to create an array for each possible value to the left of the equal sign, and add the value found to the right to the array (not add as in sum, add as in append to the array).

Visually, I think the array should look something like this:

```
Vars[
q1 [ 1,1.8 ],
q2 [ 3.2 ],
q3 [ 5.6,2.1]....]
```

End goal being I'd like to get the average, mean and median for each of q1, q2 and q3.

Is this doable in VB? I'm more familiar with PHP, but would like to keep this in Excel.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to explore `Split` function which is what you need. I'm sure you will find a lot of examples how to use this function.

Comment: Splitting isn't where I'm having problems.  I can split each cell by | and then each element by =, but I want to then create a variable array named "left side of = split" and an add elements to it.  So at the end, I'll have q1 with 65 numbers, q2 with 20 numbers, q3 with ... and so on.  There isn't a predefined number of values, or list.  It changes each time.

Comment: your question was if `Is this doable in VB?`... so, it is... with splitting, looping, dictionaries and few other possible solution mixed all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will handle an arbitrary number of "keys" (q1,q2, etc)

```
Sub Tester()

'needs a reference to microsoft scripting runtime
Dim d As New Scripting.dictionary

Dim c As Range
Dim arrP, arrE
Dim q, v, tmpV, tmpP, tmpArr, uB
Dim i As Long, n As Long
Dim k

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        tmpV = Trim(c.Value)

        If InStr(tmpV, "=") > 0 Then
            arrP = Split(tmpV, "|") 'split on pipe

            For i = LBound(arrP) To UBound(arrP)
                tmpP = arrP(i)

                If InStr(tmpP, "=") > 0 Then
                    q = Trim(Split(tmpP, "=")(0))
                    v = Trim(Split(tmpP, "=")(1))

                    If IsNumeric(v) Then
                        If Not d.exists(q) Then
                            d.Add q, Array(v)
                        Else
                            tmpArr = d(q) 'get dict value into temp array
                            uB = UBound(tmpArr) + 1
                            ReDim Preserve tmpArr(0 To uB) 'extend array
                            tmpArr(uB) = v
                            d(q) = tmpArr 'put back into dict
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next

        End If 'cell has at least one "="

    Next c

    'dump the dictionary to the immediate pane
    For Each k In d.keys
        Debug.Print k, Join(d(k), ",")
    Next k


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It's complicated, but it can be done. I tested this in excel based on your cell input, putting them in A1 and A2:

```
q1 = 1   | q2 = 3.2 | q3 = 5.6
q1 = 1.8 | q3 = 2.1 | q5 = 1.4
```

I put together a macro in Excel called "Looper" that uses two loops to cycle through the cells in column A, split them at the '|' and search for each number value, convert it to a double and place it in the corresponding array.

```
Private Sub Looper()

''Loop Variables
Dim i, k As Integer
Dim MoveDown As String

''Variables to manipulate the string
Dim Selecter As String
Dim TotalCell As String
Dim Splitter As Variant
Dim strIncrement As String

''Array variables and counters
Dim q1(50) As Double
Dim q2(50) As Double
Dim q3(50) As Double
Dim qv1, qv2, qv3 As Integer

''Variables for finding the number in each increment
Dim Equals As Integer
Dim strNumber As String
Dim dblNumber As Double

''Set the array counters to 0
qv1 = 0
qv2 = 0
qv3 = 0

i = 0

Do Until MoveDown = "DONE"
    Selector = "A" + Replace(Str(i), " ", "")
    If Range(Selector).Value = "" Then
        MoveDown = "DONE"
    Else
        TotalCell = Range(Selector).Value
        Splitter = Split(TotalCell, "|")
        For k = LBound(Splitter) To UBound(Splitter)
            ''strIncrement holds the data in between each |
            strIncrement = Splitter(k)
            ''Remove any spaces
            strIncrement = Replace(strIncrement, " ", "")
            ''Equals shows the location of the number (length of string - loc of =)
            Equals = Len(strIncrement) - InStr(1, strIncrement, "=")
            strNumber = Right(strIncrement, Equals)
            dblNumber = CDbl(strNumber)
            ''Check for the array name and then add the data to the corresponding array
            If InStr(1, strIncrement, "q1") > 0 Then
                q1(qv1) = dblNumber
                qv1 = qv1 + 1
            Else
                If InStr(1, strIncrement, "q2") > 0 Then
                    q2(qv2) = dblNumber
                    qv2 = qv2 + 1
                Else
                    If InStr(1, strIncrement, "q3") > 0 Then
                        q3(qv3) = dblNumber
                        qv3 = qv3 + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next

    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

I was able to successfully add the data to the arrays, so it should be simple to go from there to calculate the means, etc.

Comment: Wow, thanks very much.  I haven't had a chance to play with this yet, but will it work if the number of items in each cell varies? Some have 20, some have 100.  And they aren't always in the same order (some are skipped).

Comment: @McB - if you have a variable number of `q` items then I would use a `Scripting.Dictionary` with the `qX` values as the keys and arrays of elements as the values. As you add each new value to the distionary, pull out the array value into a temporary variable, use `Redim Preserve()` to extend the array, and then put it back into the Dictionary. You cannot directly manipulate an array while it's stored as the value in a dictionary.

Comment: @McB - The order and number of q's in each cell should not matter, as long as you have an array defined for each one and the necessary code for that situation (and they are all delimited the same way). The nested 'If' statement passes the value to whichever (q) array it corresponds to by looking at what is in front of the equals sign. It will work for however many q's you have defined.